# I want ON and OFF arduino Uno using this Code but it take 3 for start process

Tags: c, time, arduino, computer-science, iot

i want on and off led in automate using millis in arduino uno but somehow i solved the problem but it take some time for start minute

```
const int ledPin = 13; // Pin to control the LED

unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const unsigned long onInterval = 180000; // 3 Min in milliseconds
const unsigned long offInterval = 60000;  // 1 Min in milliseconds
bool isLedOn = false;

void setup() {
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // Set the LED pin as an output
digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
currentMillis = millis();
if (isLedOn && (currentMillis - previousMillis \>= onInterval)) {
digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // Turn off the LED
isLedOn = false;
previousMillis = currentMillis; // Reset the timer
} else if (!isLedOn && (currentMillis - previousMillis \>= offInterval)) {
digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // Turn on the LED
isLedOn = true;
previousMillis = currentMillis; // Reset the timer
}
}
```

i solved problem with this code or change coding and i if arduino board is started led want to blow

Comment: Please use indention to make your code readable.

Comment: the `\>=` operator seems incorrect to me

Answer (score 0):

1. The first LED change occurs 60 seconds after startup, because
   `isLedOn` was initialized with `false`

   But you also set the LED's state to HIGH in the setup() function
   with `digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);`

   So your loop() code thinks the LED is off, when in reality, it's
   turned on.

   Therefore it lights up for 4 minutes `(offInterval + onInterval)`,
   before turning off again.

   You can fix that, by initializing `isLedOn` with `true`.

---

2. Like @Sembei Norimaki already pointed out, the operator ">=" doesn't exist, so you should just write ">=" instead